# How can I convert 12 hour format hours into 24 hour format time in ORACLE SQL like 01-FEB-18 01.00.21.645000000 PM should be 05-01-0018 13:12:44

Tags: oracle11g

there are multiple timestamps column in oracle Sql , Now in want to convert 12 hour format time into 24 hour format time like 01-FEB-18 01.00.21.645000000 PM should be 05-01-0018 13:12:44. but I need to convert hours into 24 hours time format , I am using the below statement.

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP,'DD-MON-YYYY hh:mi:ss AM'),'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
FROM    FACT_WORK_ITEM_ACTION
WHERE TRUNC(PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP)>= '05-JUN-18'
```

But still i am getting the below error .

Error Code....

> ```
> ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required
> 01855. 00000 -  "AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> ```

Comment: Why on earth are you storing timestamp values in a VARCHAR column?

Comment: This sounds like `PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP` is already a timestamp, not a string...?

Comment: thanks for your reply but PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP  it is just a column name and it's containing date time with string value therefore this is not converting as i am using the above statement

Comment: If it was a string value you'd be getting "ORA-01722: invalid number" from the `trunc()` call. Please add the table definition to the question.

Comment: kindly check below are the table defination.

Comment: WORK_ITEM_ID CHANNEL_ID WORK_TYPE_NAME TEAM_ID PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP
105490214 2 Email 302 30-APR-18 12.56.25.432000000 PM
105490214 2 Email 302 30-APR-18 12.56.57.760000000 PM
105490080 2 Email 302 30-APR-18 12.57.05.686000000 PM
105490080 2 Email 302 30-APR-18 12.57.29.243000000 PM
105496656 12 Email 302 30-APR-18 12.57.34.298000000 PM

Comment: That is not the table *definition*. That is the table data, as formatted by your client. Use the `describe` command or query the `usr_tab_columns` view to verify the data types. And please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50794069/edit) to show the additional information, don't dump it in comments.

Comment: Are you really sure you want the full year to be 0018, no 2018? And I assume this is just a mistake in posting, but why is the time part different in your example - why does 01.00.21 convert to 13:12:44?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT to_char( TO_timestamp('01-FEB-18 01.21.01.645','dd-mon-yy hh12.mi.ss.ff'),'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
from dual;

Comment: if your column is already timestamp no need to convert it to timestamp direct use tochar(column,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

Answer (score 0):

Your `PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP` is already a timestamp, which doesn't have any intrinsic human-readable format - Oracle uses its own internal representation when storing the values.

You are just seeing that timestamp displayed by your client with formatting taken from the session NLS settings (or, possibly, overridden by the client itself).

The error is because you are doing unnecessary data type conversions and relying on implicit conversion and NLS session settings. When you do

```
TO_DATE(PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP,'DD-MON-YYYY hh:mi:ss AM')
```

you are first implicitly converting the `PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP` to a string, again using your session NLS settings, so you're effectively doing:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP),'DD-MON-YYYY hh:mi:ss AM')
```

which given the string values in your question is actually:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'DD-MON-YYYY hh:mi:ss AM')
```

The inner part of that will give a string like "01-FEB-18 01.00.21.645000000 PM" which is what you see when you query the table and the client does its own formatting. Passing that string back into `to_date()` gives the error you see, because the fractional seconds are appearing in the string where it's expecting to see the AM/PM marker:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01-FEB-18 01.00.21.645000000 PM','DD-MON-YYYY hh:mi:ss AM')
FROM DUAL;

Error report -
ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required
```

You *could* replace the implcit conversion and session values with explicit conversion and format masks:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh:mi:ss AM'),'DD-MON-YYYY hh:mi:ss AM'), 'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```

But hopefully you can tell that is doing a lot more work than it needs to -and having to use the same format mask twice is also a sign that you're doing something wrong.

The real solution is just to simplify it. You don't need to convert to a string and back to a date at all. Just do:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM FACT_WORK_ITEM_ACTION
WHERE PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP '2018-06-05 00:00:00';
```

Notice that I've also removed the `trunc()` and the comparison with a string; this now compares your timestamp column as a timestamp, which will make any index on that happier too.

Quick demo with a CTE to provide dummy data:

```
with FACT_WORK_ITEM_ACTION(PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP) as (
            select timestamp '2018-06-01 13:00:21.645000000' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2018-06-06 13:00:21.645000000' from dual
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM FACT_WORK_ITEM_ACTION
WHERE PERFORMED_TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP '2018-06-05 00:00:00';

TO_CHAR(PERFORMED_T
-------------------
06-06-2018 13:00:21
```

Comment: but still if i run the whole query then i got another error that's

Comment: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action

Comment: SELECT Distinct
  Created.WORK_ITEM_ID                                                          AS WORK_ITEM,
 Action_Da.Username                                                            As Issued_Username,
 Action_Da.First_Name || ' ' || Action_Da.Last_Name                            As Issued_Agent_Name,

Comment: Action.Agent_Id                                                               As Issued_Agent_Id,
Hand_Da.Username                                                              As Submitted_Username,
Hand_Da.First_Name || ' ' || Hand_Da.Last_Name                                As Submitted_Agent_Name,

Comment: @AnandKumar - please don't put code in comments, it's very hard to read. What you've shown can't throw that error anyway as there is no string/date manipulation; and neither can the solution in my answer. Presumably you are doing some other conversion you haven't shown, which may also be unnecessary.